# How to implement IDataReader without retyping all the methods?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, implements

I have a class that implements IDataReader and the needed functions are written, but I get an error message stating

> Class 'CSVDataReader' must implement 'Function GetBoolean(i As Integer) As Boolean' for interface 'System.Data.IDataRecord'.

IDataReader has many functions and properties. How do I implement the functions without rewriting them all?

Here is my class

```
    Public Class CSVDataReader
    Implements IDataReader
    Private stream As StreamReader
    Private columnsByName As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    Private columnsByOrdinal As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)()
    Private currentRow As String()
    Private _isClosed As Boolean = True

    Public Sub New(fileName As String)
        If Not File.Exists(fileName) Then
            Throw New Exception("File [" & fileName & "] does not exist.")
        End If

        Me.stream = New StreamReader(fileName)

        Dim headers As String() = stream.ReadLine().Split(",")
        For i As Integer = 0 To headers.Length - 1
            columnsByName.Add(headers(i), i)
            columnsByOrdinal.Add(i, headers(i))
        Next

        _isClosed = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub Close()
        If stream IsNot Nothing Then
            stream.Close()
        End If
        _isClosed = True
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property FieldCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return columnsByName.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This is the main function that does the work - it reads in the next line of data and parses the values into ordinals.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>A value indicating whether the EOF was reached or not.</returns>
    Public Function Read() As Boolean
        If stream Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If
        If stream.EndOfStream Then
            Return False
        End If

        currentRow = stream.ReadLine().Split(",")
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Function GetValue(i As Integer) As Object
        Return currentRow(i)
    End Function

    Public Function GetName(i As Integer) As String
        Return columnsByOrdinal(i)
    End Function

    Public Function GetOrdinal(name As String) As Integer
        Return columnsByName(name)
    End Function

    Public Function GetOrdinal(name As String) As Integer
        Return columnsByName(name)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: in VS you should be able to right click on the Interface name in your code and select "Implement Interface".  This will stub out all of the Interface methods for you.  Works for C#, I assume VB also supports it.

Comment: Sadly, VB doesn't have much refactoring goodness like that (at least the last time I looked; maybe later versions are better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement all the methods and properties.

An interface is a contract - if an object says it can provide the services listed on the interface, it has to provide all of them. An interface is not a base class - there is no "template" code to fall back on if you don't implement something.

It's OK not to put any code in the methods/properties you aren't interested in (I usually put `Throw New NotImplementedException` so I know when I've inadvertently called a method I wasn't planning to). But the stubs have to be there.

Comment: Visual Studio should have populated your class with the stubs when you hit the `Enter` key after typing `Implements IDataReader`. If it didn't, try deleting that line and retyping it, making sure to press the `Enter` key at the end of the line. If you type the line and then just click somewhere else in the file, Visual Studio won't auto-populate your class.

Comment: So I did that and many of the autogenerated functions that are meant to return a value do not have a return statement. What do you suggest?

Comment: Although VS shows it as an error, when I upload it it did not throw an error. Problem solved.

Comment: If you put in the `Throw` statement I mentioned, VS will stop telling you the method doesn't return a value. Alternatively, you can put in `Return Nothing`. (In Visual Basic, [Nothing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx) is the default value for a type, so `Return Nothing` will work whether the method returns a reference type, such as `Object`, or a value type, such as `Integer`.